# OSM Nominatim Server Installation Projection Error

Tags: osm2pgsql

Environment:

Ubuntu 12.4
Postgresql 9.1.4
PostGIS 2.0.1
Latest Nominatim installation instructions posted at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation

The installation is failing with (command built by the Nominatim php build script):

/osm2pgsql/osm2pgsql -lsc -O gazetteer --hstore -C 1100 -d nominatim /home/user/osm_data/central-america.osm

The -l tag is causing the following error:

Projection code failed to initialise

osm2pgsql SVN version 0.80.0 (64bit id space)

ERROR: Error executing external command: /home/user/Nominatim/osm2pgsql/osm2pgsql -lsc -O gazetteer --hstore -C 1059 -d nominatim /home/user/osm_data/central-america.osm.pbf

In trying to troubleshoot, where is the -l tag pulling the projection code from?  I can get the import to run without the -l but the import later fails with an SRID error which I can only suppose results from this initial error.

Can anyone enlighten me on what I should be looking at to fix the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Found a discussion about a similar problem at http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/wQWIbp8uENgQyNoCJGQz.  Even though the discussion happened several years ago the information provided to troubleshoot is still relevant.

In doing some of the troubleshooting listed in this discussion I was able to identify and resolve the problem.

Thanks to Jon Burgess for providing the level of detail that he did in that discussion.

JAM